# puppeteer howto find element within parent element

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

with [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) I can find child element `within` element as following:

```
cy.get('div#Login_form).within(() => {
  cy.get('input[name="human[email]"]').type('John')
  cy.get('input[name="human[password]"]').type('123456')
})
```

Is there any equivalence in `Puppeteer` for `within()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well one thing you can do is to declare your CSS selector paths as follows:

```
await page.type('div#Login_form > input[name="human[email]"]', 'John');
await page.type('div#Login_form > input[name="human[password]"]', '123456');
```

Another alternative, which might prove easier to read (even if it does mean more lines of code) would be to do the following:

```
// Get the form element
const form = await page.$('div#Login_form');

// Get the email and password elements from the form
const email = await form.$('input[name="human[email]"]');
const password = await form.$('input[name="human[password]"]');

// Type the data into each element
await email.type('John');
await password.type('123456');
```

Comment: <div class="MuiCardHeader-content"><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiCardHeader-title jss249 MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-displayBlock">Card-671</span><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiCardHeader-subheader jss250 MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorTextSecondary MuiTypography-displayBlock">10/11/2021</span></div>       Here i wanted to get the text from 2nd span. I am using "div.MuiCardHeader-content > span[2]" selector, i am getting invalid selector error. Can anyone please help me with syntax.

Comment: @Explorer you can't use array indexes like that in CSS selectors. What you will need to do is use Puppeteers equivalent of `querySelectorAll` and then pick out your element that way as follows:

const spanText = await page.$$eval('div.MuiCardHeader-content > span', (spans) => spans[1].textContent);

Comment: i am getting "1" as output after using your code, but we need to get the complete date , can you please help me in getting complete date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `waitForFunction` method with a helper method:

```js
const getChildElement = (handle, selector, options = {}) => {
  const node = handle.querySelector(selector)

  if (!node) return null

  if (options.text && !node.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim().includes(options.text)) {
    return null
  }

  // other checks...

  return node
}

const container = await page.$('#container')
page.waitForFunction(getChildElement, {}, container, '.child', {text: 'Text'})
```